# Where are Pip installation logs?

Tags: python, pip

Why doesn't pip make logs of which version of which lib was installed when? If you update a library to a broken version then what? How do you know which version is not broken?

---

Those who upvote this - can you tell me why are you doing it?

Comment: How do you know which version is not broken? You test them. If you upgrade a library to a broken version? Upgrade (or downgrade) to a working one.

Comment: Old version is obviously not broken. Any idea why I talk about **logs**?

Comment: Ideally, it would be recorded in your `requirements.txt`. Why is it `pip`'s responsibility to track things for you? Anyway, if you want a log, you can get it via `--log` option to `pip`; but it does not make one by default.

Comment: @Amadan Because it can do it? What requirements? I just made pip install -U

Comment: That's not an ideal way to use Python packages, pretty much exactly because of what happened to you. Take a look at [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (or [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) before Python 3.6) and [requirements files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files).

Comment: @Amadan so you should never update your libraries? Is it what you want to say?

Comment: No; but if you update them, do it in a controlled fashion, with your working configuration safely frozen in a requirements file, so that you can go back to working state; also, preferably with each project in an isolated environment so that the changes in one project's requirements do not impact another project. Updating all your modules at once is asking for trouble, really.

Comment: Small programs likely do not need a full-blown virtual environment, but if they use more than a couple of libraries they likely would benefit from a requirements file.

Comment: @Amadan I think we live in different worlds. Yes, I agree, that projects that are deployed elsewhere require requirements.txt.

Comment: Before i update, I save the output of "pip list" to a file, In larger projects I version this file using git. You can see why it is not automatic because you dont use all pip packages in all your projects. You only care about the ones you use. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/

Comment: While I can understand your complaints as many things in `pip` leave much to be desired, you are expecting `pip` to be a full blown package manager which it isn't. Like other tools often seen as package managers (such as `npm` or `gem`), `pip` is only a tool to put python modules where they are importable, nothing more. It doesn't have and will probably never have features like transaction rollbacks or dependency cycle resolution etc.

Comment: @hoefling And is there a "real" package manager for python?

Answer (score 63):

When you run the pip, you can specify the logfile. This way you can track the installation logs in future.

```
pip install pylint --log LOG_FILE
```

Or you can set it in your pip.conf to be enabled by default:

```
[global]
log = <path>
```

Hope this helps.However this is not exactly what you asked. This is just to help achieve that.
For windows:
Quoting from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

```
On Windows the configuration file is %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini.
```

Note: Once you configure the global file it gets all those logs which you get when you run pip in verbose mode. This also means once you configure pip.conf file you dont need to run pip in verbose mode. It will log messages by default.

Comment: I want it to be done authomatically. Will it record which library is upgraded from which version to which?

Comment: then you prefer the enable by default method. It will log those messages which comes when you run pip in verbose mode. So, definetely you need to dig the log to understand as it may not be in format and clear in which you want.

Comment: Better than nothing. Where is that conf on windows? And what if I have different pythons?

Comment: Don't quite get, so output from all python installations will be merged to one file, without any hint about version/path?

Comment: run the pip command in verbose mode. It will display everything even errors those things will come to this file. So, it has all info you need.

Comment: Can it be saved to that config? I want to run pip as usual. Seems pip failed that job, and it just costed me 1/2 hour or more. Unpayed!

Comment: yes, so in short. Once you configure the global file it gets all those logs which you get when you run pip in verbose mode. This also means once you configure pip.conf file you dont need to run pip in verbose mode. It will log messages by default

Comment: Please update the answer with your helpful "yes, so in short" comment - it is very helpful but buried were people will miss it. And add that for Linux the file is in $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf