# pip + what is the equivalent approach to yum history with pip

Tags: python, linux, pip

I am searching a way to find when pip installed the pkgs like `yum history`

```
yum history
Loaded plugins: langpacks
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    42 | -y install libffi-devel* | 2020-06-09 01:07 | Install        |    1
    41 | -y install rabbitmq-serv | 2020-06-09 01:07 | Install        |   21
    40 | install -y gcc-gfortran. | 2020-06-09 01:06 | Install        |    2
    39 | install -y gcc-c++.x86_6 | 2020-06-09 01:06 | Install        |    2
    38 | -y install python-twiste | 2020-06-09 00:55 | Install        |    1
    37 | -y install python-zope-i | 2020-06-09 00:55 | Install        |    1
    36 | -y install yum install p | 2020-06-09 00:55 | Install        |    1
```

as all can see above , `yum history` described exactly the installtion progress of rpm's

what is the same approach to find the pkgs that installed by pip ?

***example:***

`yum history` can show what is the rpm's that removed maybe during rpm dependencies
so , we want to see the same with pip  - is it possible ?

```
32 | remove -y python2-crypto | 2020-06-09 00:55 | Erase          |    3 EE
```

***second*** - we have strange isshue about ansible pkgs that was installed by pip for sure , but after some other installation we not see the ansible by `pip freeze | grep ansible`

I used the following python script to get the list of installed pkgs

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Prints when python packages were installed
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
import os
import pip


if __name__ == "__main__":
    packages = []
    for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
        package_name_version = str(package)
        try:
            module_dir = next(package._get_metadata('top_level.txt'))
            package_location = os.path.join(package.location, module_dir)
            os.stat(package_location)
        except (StopIteration, OSError):
            try:
                package_location = os.path.join(package.location, package.key)
                os.stat(package_location)
            except:
                package_location = package.location
        modification_time = os.path.getctime(package_location)
        modification_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(modification_time)
        packages.append([
            modification_time,
            package_name_version
        ])
    for modification_time, package_name_version in sorted(packages):
        print("{0} - {1}".format(modification_time,
                                 package_name_version))
```

*but the problem is that script cant tell us if ansible pkgs was removed*

Comment: If you did not log it you won't have any history. You can enable logging globally. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844927/where-are-pip-installation-logs That will be logs, not a formatted report, but the info will be there.

Comment: Note though that I do not really see the use case for knowing the time at which a package was installed. Would you rather not know the versions? In which case `pip freeze` does that.

Comment: see the update , it is important to understand if someway the pkgs was removed

Comment: I am sorry I still do not see the use case. Your dependencies are supposed to be in a `requirements.txt` file, that is managed by your revision control system. Thus the change of dependencies should be visible through the revisions of that file.

Comment: the target is to know why some pkg that installed by ansible was removed after some time by maybe other installation

Comment: What version of python are you using ? How did you install ansible ?

Comment: we have python 2.7 , and the latest version of ansible ( we installed the ansible by pip )

Comment: I'm using 3.7, created a virtual environment, installed ansible using pip, then un-installed it. After that I found no trace at all of ansible. So it seems pip does not keep any trace of deleted packages. You need to find other source to find out deletion.