# How to restore previous package version in pip?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, version

I work in two machines separately with two pandas versions (yes, I know this is not ideal), and I have recently tried to upgrade my pandas package in one of my machines, but now I am experiencing tons of bugs. The thing is, my requirements.txt had registered only the pandas version of my other machine (the one I did not upgrade). So now I need to downgrade my first machine package to the previous version I was working with, but I don't what version that is.

With that said, is there any way I could find an upgrade log, or maybe a built-in pip tool that might help me downgrade pandas version to whatever the previous version was?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Exzmple for termcolor2

```py
C:\Users\your user>pip show termcolor2
Name: termcolor2
Version: 0.0.3
Summary: simple termcolor wrapper
Home-page: https://github.com/v2e4lisp/termcolor2
Author: Yan Wenjun
Author-email: mylastnameisyan@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\areza\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: termcolor
Required-by:

# in venv
(venv) C:\Users\your user>pip install termcolor2==0.0.2

# not in venv
C:\Users\your user>pip install termcolor2==0.0.2 -U
...
```

"pip show" help

```
C:\Users\your user>pip show -h

Usage:
  pip show [options] <package> ...

Description:
  Show information about one or more installed packages.

  The output is in RFC-compliant mail header format.

Show Options:
  -f, --files                 Show the full list of installed files for each package.

General Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help.
  --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
  -V, --version               Show version and exit.
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to
                              WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
  --log <path>                Path to a verbose appending log.
  --no-input                  Disable prompting for input.
  --proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
  --retries <retries>         Maximum number of retries each connection should attempt (default 5 times).
  --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
  --exists-action <action>    Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup,
                              (a)bort.
  --trusted-host <hostname>   Mark this host or host:port pair as trusted, even though it does not have valid or any
                              HTTPS.
  --cert <path>               Path to PEM-encoded CA certificate bundle. If provided, overrides the default. See 'SSL
                              Certificate Verification' in pip documentation for more information.
  --client-cert <path>        Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing the private key and the
                              certificate in PEM format.
  --cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.
  --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
  --disable-pip-version-check
                              Don't periodically check PyPI to determine whether a new version of pip is available for
                              download. Implied with --no-index.
  --no-color                  Suppress colored output.
  --no-python-version-warning
                              Silence deprecation warnings for upcoming unsupported Pythons.
  --use-feature <feature>     Enable new functionality, that may be backward incompatible.
  --use-deprecated <feature>  Enable deprecated functionality, that will be removed in the future.
```

```
pip install name==version
    install a special version
```

Comment: pip freeze only shows you the installed version, not the previous one, so this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

by default pip only logs into the console, if you still have it open you could search on it, for future reference it's possible to specify a log file check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53844983/3395862

I am assuming you are not using a version control system like git either, so I am afraid your best bet is to install a pandas version that roughly matches the date your code was created [from this list](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#history)