# Where to find version of previously installed Python packages in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I updated a package to the latest version with `pip` recently but there is an incompatibility. For this reason I would like to install the previously installed version of this package but I don't know which one it's. How can I know the version number ?

Comment: Related, same problem different question: [Where are Pip installation logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53844927/11082165)

Comment: @Brian thanks for pointing me this question