# pip3 install gives me error 128 when trying to install from github

Tags: git, pip, git-clone

I am trying to install wav2vec and per instructions on their github I'm using

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/vasudevgupta7/gsoc-wav2vec2@main
```

it gives me

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://github.com/vasudevgupta7/gsoc-wav2vec2 /tmp/pip-req-build-7pnrs747 Check the logs for full command output.

what is the problem?

Comment: Did you examine `/tmp/pip-req-build-7pnrs747`? What does it contain?

Comment: If the file is no longer there, reproduce the error and examine the new file it creates.

Comment: there's only /tmp/ which contains: tmpf2u4xql4_kernels and tmpt9m6uztc_kernels

Comment: @tripleee `/tmp/pip-req-build-7pnrs747` is the temporary target directory pip was trying to use to do the `git clone`, so it would be gone. @NiloufarModir: find the "logs" that the error message refers to (`Check the logs for full command output`) and tell us what's in those logs.

Comment: how can check the logs? what is the command for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844927/where-are-pip-installation-logs