# How to see previous pandas version after upgrading with pip?

Tags: pandas

I upgraded my pandas package yesterday using `pip`. Is there any way I can see what the previous version I had before my upgrade?

Comment: You can probably see it in the log file.

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry I'm new to this. where is the log?

Comment: Hi, it might be too late for that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53844927/11246056