# ERROR: Complete output from command : Error installing spaCy using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm, spacy

i have searched everywhere and tried many possible ways to install spaCy on my system using pip.

tried updating pip, setuptools,

tried running `cmd` with administrator privileges

tried installing the required modules seperately.

tried creating a virtual environment for installation, but still run into problem.

this is the full outputError :

```
ERROR:Complete output from command 'c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe' 'c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --p
refix 'C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-132qxoud\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'w
heel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.0.0.dev6:
  ERROR: Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/51/f45cea425fd5cb0b0380f5b0f048ebc1da5b417e48d304838c02d6288a1e/setuptools-41.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/cf/12a002d94d1f52be048936e1f88292ee3fdce396d677caa7be7d3561031f/Cython-0.29.10-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/79/42db53e48df72e88be9294f0253c4c7905d89a8d1f065c3661c56a8723c9/cymem-2.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/03/149f83b73b5f597b6e7a5689dab7959a8c74759a47c30cb1fd2b74bf9686/preshed-2.0.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
  Collecting thinc==7.0.0.dev6
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/9b/62c60d2f5bc135d2aa1d8c8a86aaf84edb719a59c7f11a4316259e61a298/plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/3d/7a6b68b631d2ab54975f3a4863f3c4e9b26445353264ef01f465dc9b0208/tqdm-4.32.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.5 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
  Collecting six<2.0.0,>=1.10.0 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wrapt<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/c1/d76ccdd12c716be79162d934fe7de4ac8a318b9302864716dde940641a79/wasabi-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/9e/84a83616cbe5daa94909da38b780e93bf566dc2113c3dc35d7b4cad52f63/blis-0.2.4.tar.gz
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/98/cecf557b7f3f1dfac93171392887e4f7a606d6867752311c56a30742d581/numpy-1.16.4-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
  Collecting thinc-gpu-ops<0.1.0,>=0.0.1 (from thinc==7.0.0.dev6)
  Building wheels for collected packages: blis
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for blis (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BLACKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-i
nstall-f6_iu3k9\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'
exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-vghry0um' --python-tag cp36:
    ERROR: BLIS_COMPILER? None
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
    copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
    running build_ext
    msvc
    py_compiler msvc
    {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar
=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*
.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;3
1:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jp
g=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.sv
g=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=
01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*
.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=
00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV': '
/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/sha
re:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/
usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documen
ts/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Managem
ent Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/Syste
m32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program
 Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program File
s/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM/b
in:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/
Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle
/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRANT_
HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
    clang -c C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6_iu3k9\blis\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpct0rqpqv\bli_
cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\fram
e\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6_iu3k9\blis\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis
  Failed to build blis
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, cymem, preshed, murmurhash, plac, tqdm, srsly, six, wrapt, wasabi, numpy, blis, thinc-gpu-ops, thinc
    Running setup.py install for blis: started
      Running setup.py install for blis: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BLACKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip
-install-f6_iu3k9\\blis\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'
"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fq1behqz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\pip-build-env-132qxoud\overlay' --compile:
      ERROR: BLIS_COMPILER? None
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.6
      creating build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
      copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
      copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
      copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
      creating build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis\tests
      copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
      copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
      copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
      copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\blis
      running build_ext
      msvc
      py_compiler msvc
      {'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.t
ar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31
:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01
;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.
jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.
svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.q
t=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35
:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.og
a=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'HOSTTYPE': 'x86_64', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'OLDPWD': '/home/matt/repos/flame-blis', 'VIRTUAL_ENV':
 '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6', 'USER': 'matt', 'PWD': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis', 'HOME': '/home/matt', 'NAME': 'LAPTOP-OMKOB3VM', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/s
hare:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LOGNAME': 'matt', 'PATH': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin:/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin
:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu/Scripts:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Docum
ents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5:/mnt/c/Users/matt/Documents/cmder/vendor/conemu-maximus5/ConEmu:/mnt/c/Python37/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python37:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Manag
ement Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/Sys
tem32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Progr
am Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Fi
les/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/LLVM
/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/
c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/matt/AppData/Roaming/npm:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Orac
le/VirtualBox', 'PS1': '(env3.6) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: \\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ', 'VAGRAN
T_HOME': '/home/matt/.vagrant.d/', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', '_': '/home/matt/repos/cython-blis/env3.6/bin/python'}
      clang -c C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6_iu3k9\blis\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3_mv1lsn\bl
i_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -funroll-all-loops -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.0-6" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\fr
ame\ind\ukernels\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6_iu3k9\blis\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command "'c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\BLACKL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f6_iu3k9\\blis\
\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install -
-record 'C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fq1behqz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-13
2qxoud\overlay' --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\BLACKL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f6_iu3k9\blis\
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe' 'c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\BLACKL
~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-132qxoud\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' C
ython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.0.0.dev6" failed with error code 1 in None
`
```

Comment: You could try `pip3 install wheel` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204916/what-is-the-meaning-of-failed-building-wheel-for-x-in-pip-install

Answer (score 2):

Using an x86-64 ("64-bit") version of Python instead of x86 ("32-bit") one on Windows fixed the issue for me.