# Unable to install spacy using pip install spacy

Tags: python, anaconda, spacy

I attempt to install spacy in my `Python` using `conda install spacy` at `anaconda` prompt. 
However, the prompt returns a lot of conflicts. 
Some of them are

```
Package lxml conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.07=py3_0 -> lxml==4.3.4=py3h1350720_0

Package openpyxl conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.07=py3_0 -> openpyxl==2.6.2=py_0

Package regex conflicts for:
spacy -> regex[version='2017.4.5|>=2017.4.0,<201.12.1|>=2017.4.0,<=2018.6.21>=2017.4.0,<=2018.7.11|>=2017.4.1,<2017.12.1|>=2018.01.10']
```

I tried `pip install spacy` as well. 
But after installing build dependencies, the prompt returns a lot of spacy error complete output from command.
The full error list is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666186/error-complete-output-from-command-error-installing-spacy-using-pip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://spacy.io/usage, you can install `spacy` using `conda` command as:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any issue still you can use directly in **google colab** with out installation. 
And Run the below command in Anaconda Prompt (Run as administrator)

`conda install -c conda-forge spacy`
Install language model
`python -m spacy download en`