# pip install requirements version/dependences conflict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I would like to run the project https://github.com/bedangSen/VoiceSens on my Windows 10 machine. The manual on the project site is straightforward, but I am not able to resolve the dependencies problem. I can not execute pip install -r requirements.txt without an error. I tried a manual modification of pypi versions in the requirements.txt file without any success. I think there must be another approach to run older Python projects. I use Python 3.8.5, so I don't think the version is in general to high on my PC, thus the project site says Python 3 in required.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: ERROR: Failed building wheel for XXX for mostly all packages

Comment: I tried it also on a Linux system with Anaconda, when I execute in the create environment pip install -r /pahtToTheRequiremnts.txt I get this error  https://pastebin.com/9nPXcMt0

Comment: seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204916/what-is-the-meaning-of-failed-building-wheel-for-x-in-pip-install