# Having a problem installing fbprophet (facebook prophet) on my laptop through CMD

Tags: python

Every time I try installing through pip install fbprophet it starts downloading all the dependencies just fine but then after sometime gives me the error below before continuing to download other dependencies. But when I try to import it after in my project if tells me its missing.
,,,

```
     ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
```

Comment: Does this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204916/what-is-the-meaning-of-failed-building-wheel-for-x-in-pip-install answer your question?