# Getting "Building wheel for Scorer (setup.py) ... error"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, sklearn-pandas

I am installing "Scorer". Commands used:

1. pip install sklearn metrics Scorer
2. pip install sklearn metrics Scorer --no-cache-dir

Any idea on the below error. I already tried referring options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53204916/what-is-the-meaning-of-failed-building-wheel-for-x-in-pip-install)

I have uploaded the log file here. Pls. check and let me know if you are not able to access it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1loP7KrxqNJ_TNrlEzjhipTjSxgUXw0Yt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please post the complete error output? It looks like the end is missing, and I suspect the source of the error is there.

Comment: uploaded log file now. I was not able to paste it here as it was detecting it as code and was not letting me submit, no matter what I do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27basetsd.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory