# Problems installing Python av in Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyav

```py
C:\Windows.old\Users\chris>pip install av
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting av
  Using cached av-10.0.0.tar.gz (2.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [74 lines of output]
      Compiling av\buffer.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\buffer.pyx
      Compiling av\bytesource.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\bytesource.pyx
      Compiling av\descriptor.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\descriptor.pyx
      Compiling av\dictionary.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\dictionary.pyx
      Compiling av\enum.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\enum.pyx
      Compiling av\error.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\error.pyx
      Compiling av\format.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\format.pyx
      Compiling av\frame.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\frame.pyx
      performance hint: av\logging.pyx:232:5: Exception check on 'log_callback' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
      Possible solutions:
          1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
          2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      cdef const char *log_context_name(void *ptr) nogil:
          cdef log_context *obj = <log_context*>ptr
          return obj.name

      cdef lib.AVClass log_class
      log_class.item_name = log_context_name
                            ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      av\logging.pyx:216:22: Cannot assign type 'const char *(void *) except? NULL nogil' to 'const char *(*)(void *) noexcept nogil'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'const char *(void *) except? NULL nogil'.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...

      # Start the magic!
      # We allow the user to fully disable the logging system as it will not play
      # nicely with subinterpreters due to FFmpeg-created threads.
      if os.environ.get('PYAV_LOGGING') != 'off':
          lib.av_log_set_callback(log_callback)
                                  ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      av\logging.pyx:351:28: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, int, const char *, va_list) except * nogil' to 'av_log_callback'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, int, const char *, va_list) except * nogil'.
      Compiling av\logging.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing av\logging.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4nz2e7u1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4nz2e7u1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4nz2e7u1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4nz2e7u1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 157, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4nz2e7u1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4nz2e7u1\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: av\logging.pyx
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I have no idea about this error I think. What can I try next?

Comment: Maybe try with solutions in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53204916/17457846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not Windows 11.
The problem lies within `python 3.12` .
The package `av` is not yet released for `python 3.12`.

Please try to install `av` under `python 3.11`.