# what can i do to solve this error while installing a python module?

Tags: python, pip, module

I was installing a module with the comand 'pip install [module]' and this error went :

```
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for srsly
      Failed to build preshed thinc blis srsly
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, srsly, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

What can i do ??

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/56504270/12890458 answers your question

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not the same and the solution doesnt work... but thank you for answering. I was instaling the Chatterbot module, and the problem appeared when it was building dependencies, at the end of the processus. I think it's a problem with C, compilation and this kind of stuff...

Comment: please include the complete error message as text in the question

Comment: the erro is too long to be writen here, here is a code share : https://codeshare.io/XLOPzK

Comment: Your error message says you should get Microsoft Visual C++ 14 or greater. Have you done that?

Comment: The problem is that I've tried to get Microsoft Visual C 14 or higher but I don't have administrator rights on my laptop, so I can't. If I manage to find a zip file of the software, where do I unzip it and if I do, will it work?